# Double Click Row of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to be able to double click the row of a `GridView` and be redirected to a page that shows the details of the row that was clicked.

I have code that I'm working with and it seems like it should work, but I'm getting the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

For some reason the row comes up null and I'm unsure why.  My code is below.  Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" EnableViewState="true" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderStyle="Solid" GridLines="Both" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#990033" Width="1000px" 
    DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1">
     <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
    <Columns>            
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("intBatchID") %>' NavigateUrl="TestPage1.aspx?intBatchID={0}" Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="vcharName" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="vcharName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="dtmScheduled" HeaderText="Date Scheduled" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="dtmScheduled" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="intBatchPriorityLevel" 
            HeaderText="Priority Level" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="intBatchPriorityLevel" />
    </Columns>
    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" Position="TopAndBottom" PageButtonCount="4" PreviousPageText="Previous" NextPageText="Next" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" />
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />        
</asp:GridView>   
You are viewing page <%=GridView1.PageIndex + 1%> of <%=GridView1.PageCount%>
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" OnSelected="EntityDataSource1_Selected"  
    ConnectionString="name=TestEntities" DefaultContainerName="TestEntities" 
    EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="tbl_Batch" 
    Select="it.[intBatchID], it.[vcharName], it.[dtmScheduled], it.[intBatchPriorityLevel]" OrderBy="it.[intBatchID]">
</asp:EntityDataSource>



protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            System.Data.DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", String.Format("window.location='TestPage1.aspx?intBatchID={0}'", drv["intBatchID"]));
        }

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "Highlight(this)");
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onMouseOut", "UnHighlight(this)");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would put some checks in place. Secondly, from your comments, it looks like you are dealing with a `MaterializedDataRecord`, so trying to cast it as a `DataRowView` isn't going to work.

---

## C#

Try casting it as a `DbDataRecord`:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var dr = e.Row.DataItem as System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord;

        if (dr != null && !Convert.IsDBNull(dr["intBatchID"]))
        {
            int intBatchId;
            int.TryParse(dr["intBatchID"].ToString(), out intBatchId);

            if (intBatchId > 0)
            {
                string js = "ChangeBatchId(" + intBatchId.ToString() + ");";
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", js);
            }
        }
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "Highlight(this);");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onMouseOut", "UnHighlight(this);");
    }
}
```

---

## JAVASCRIPT

```
function ChangeBatchId(batchId)
{
    // uncomment to debug batch id.
    // console.log("BatchID: " + batchId.toString());

    window.location.href = 'TestPage1.aspx?intBatchID=' + batchId.toString();
}
```